# Unable to Deploy Hexo Blog on GitHub Pages

Tags: github, http-status-code-404, github-pages, hexo

I am attempting to deploy my blog on GitHub Pages using Hexo, but I am encountering a 404 error. I have tried numerous solutions but to no avail. Here are the details:

Node.js version: 9.7.2
Hexo version: 6.3.0
I can generate the page on my localhost (the hexo server command works as expected).
I have correctly named my repository and set the deploy configuration in _config.yml as follows:

```
# Deployment
## Docs: https://hexo.io/docs/one-command-deployment
deploy:
  type: git
  repo: https://github.com/shioubi0216/shioubi0216.github.io.git
  branch: main
```

I have ensured that the local repository is synchronized with the remote repository.
I have tried resetting the repository (deleting and recreating the GitHub Pages repository), but it didn't help.
I have installed the hexo-deployer-git package using
`npm install hexo-deployer-git --save` multiple times.
I encountered a build failure with Jekyll at one point, and I set `skip_render: true`, but the website is still not working.
I have checked the GitHub Pages troubleshooting guide for 404 errors, and the status seems fine.
I don't believe I am using DNS, but here is the URL configuration in _config.yml:

```
# URL
## Set your site url here. For example, if you use GitHub Page, set url as 'https://username.github.io/project'
url: https://shioubi0216.github.io/
permalink: :year/:month/:day/:title/
permalink_defaults:
pretty_urls:
  trailing_index: true # Set to false to remove trailing 'index.html' from permalinks
  trailing_html: true # Set to false to remove trailing '.html' from permalinks
```

I have cleared my browser cache and restarted my PC multiple times.
I noticed that I don't have an `index.html` file. I had one in my Hexo directory earlier, but even with it, I couldn't deploy the site. I am unsure if this is related to the problem.
I have verified that the repository on GitHub is on the main branch.
Despite numerous attempts, I am unable to resolve this issue. I am turning to the Stack Overflow community for help. I am quite exhausted and considering resetting my PC if I can't find a solution soon. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[My github.io repo link](https://github.com/shioubi0216/shioubi0216.github.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the `repo:` part of `_config.yml` to the **original github Https link** to **SSH link**, and it work!
I have no idea why it work. but I success HAHAHA.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Jheng Syu is great. It works for me. I added my the deploy section of _config.yaml configuration in case anyone want to known the details.

```
deploy:
  type: git
  repo: 
    github:
      url: 'git@github.com:yaohuiwu/yaohuiwu.github.io.git'
      branch: master
```

Comment: I can't comment Jheng Syu's answer because it warns me that I must have 50 reputations.